# Compilation Errors with usb_buffer_free and usb_buffer_alloc

Tags: android, linux, compiler-errors, kernel-module

Hi Im having errors with compiling in usbtouchscreen.c into the kernel drivers.
I have attached the usbtouchsreen.c file to the post also.

```
 CC      drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.o
drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.c: In function 'usbtouch_free_buffers':
drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.c:856: error: implicit declaration of function 'usb_buffer_free'
drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.c: In function 'usbtouch_probe':
drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.c:890: error: implicit declaration of function 'usb_buffer_alloc'
drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.c:891: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
make[3]: *** [drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [drivers/input/touchscreen] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/input] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

I have included the source here: http://pastebin.com/GTsic7Bg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your driver quite old (or for an older kernel, perhaps)? Perhaps you want to take a look at this rename:

https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/4/12/132

It seems to be in the latest kernel at least:

http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/drivers/usb/core/usb.c#L698

In fact it seems to have gone into 2.6.34 or thereabouts.

Comment: Linux/arm 2.6.37 Kernel. It was compiling up until a few days ago, Im not sure what changed.

Comment: You didn't, by any chance, change kernel (or change something that led to a new kernel)? I'm 99.9% sure that my answer is the right one - the function you have WAS part of the 2.6.34 kernel, and its name changed in the patch sent to LKML in the first link. Exactly those two functions and nothing else. So it suggests that you were compiling against an older kernel (header file). What have you changed... ?

Comment: Thank you, you where correct. I was using the wrong usbtouchscreen.c file.

Comment: Ah, that is a good explanation. Glad to hear you got it sorted.